# SUM and Subtract result depending by column result in Mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT cashtransactionstatus_id, SUM(cashtransaction_amount) AS cashtransaction_amount 
    FROM cash_transactions 
    WHERE cashpaymenttype_id = 1 
    GROUP BY (cashtransactionstatus_id);
```

This query returns:

[image]

How i can return only one digit number `endtotal` subtracting and sum depending by the column `cashtransactionstatus_id`? Ex:

SUM `Status(1,3): 1195.00 as col1`

SUM `Status(2,4,5): 430.00 as col2`

then `show (col1 - col2) AS endtotal` `= 765.00`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregates:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN cashtransactionstatus_id IN (1,3) THEN cashtransaction_amount END) -
       SUM(CASE WHEN cashtransactionstatus_id IN (2,4,5) THEN cashtransaction_amount END) AS endtotal
FROM cash_transactions 
WHERE cashpaymenttype_id = 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd93a/6)